Changes to Poker moderator team, and scheduling a moderator election
You may have noticed that some moderators on your site have lost their moderator access today. On July 8th, 2024, we released a new version of the moderator agreement. Moderators network-wide had 30 days to sign the new agreement. Of the 600 moderators network-wide, around 44 did not sign the new revision of the moderator agreement by the deadline. As a result, those 44 moderators’ diamonds were removed today.
While we are generally satisfied with this outcome, unfortunately some sites lost more moderators than others. On Poker, there is only one moderator remaining as of today.
We are currently in the process of scheduling new elections where needed, and we will prioritize sites like Poker that have been harder hit by this change. Until a new election concludes, Community Managers (Stack Exchange employees) will be checking on Poker occasionally to assist with moderation. However, please be aware that it may take a bit longer than normal for flags to be handled.
We would encourage you to begin discussing and organizing your community for an election, and we’ll be around to schedule one soon.
In the meantime, we strongly encourage curators to use site curation tools to the best of your ability (up/down voting, closing, editing, flagging, and reviewing), in order to provide a good experience for users of Poker in the interim. If you see anything that needs immediate staff attention, please feel free to contact us.

As I said after the previous scheduled election failed due to insufficient candidates,

That would mean Poker SE kept running, and it seems at this point more clearly than ever, Stack Exchange needs to start culling the sites that don't work.

Keeping the site live, let alone scheduling an election with few candidates and few voters is a waste of resources.
An update on the statistics.
Poker SE does not have the content to justify a separate site.

from SEDE's latest information, Poker SE still has less than 2200 questions and less than 4700 answers to match, across 131 tags.

the single tag of Magic: the Gathering on Board & Card Games SE, which sees repeated Area 51 proposals for a separate site, has over 5000 questions, and over 8800 answers to them.


Poker SE does not have the user base necessary to be called a community.

a minimum 64 out of 100 users created in the last 45 days are spammers of some kind (1 rep, DisplayName is a commercial company, often from a location or industry repeated beyond coincidental likelihood). 26 are explicitly identified with "spam" or "spammer" in their username!

of those 100 new users, exactly one has received any rep on the site (from a single answer with +2 -1 voting), and eight altogether have received the association bonus.

in this quarter, only one user gained the reputation equivalent of at least two upvotes - and they're the only current moderator.

in this quarter, six others have gained the equivalent of at least one upvote, and eight altogether have earned positive rep change.


Poker SE does not have the user base necessary to justify an election.

150 rep is needed to be eligible to vote. Only 86 eligible voters have visited the site in the last year, and only 26 in the last quarter. This includes 8 users who are one upvote short, only 1 of whom visited in the last quarter.

300 rep is needed to nominate as a candidates. Only 50 eligible nominees have visited the site in the last year, and only 14 of them in the last quarter.


